# How to find how many times a specific element is repeated in an array?

Tags: arrays, c, function, random

I have generated an array that has 10 integers. I have to find how many times an element has been repeated, but I always get `0` as an output. Here in this code, `countcolor` variables is my count values. For example `countcolor1` is my count value for the integer `1`. Here is what I have so far:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>

int i;

double entropy_calculator(int bucket[10]);

int main() {
    srand(time(NULL));
    int countings;

    int bucket[10];
    for (i = 0; i < 10; ++i) {
        bucket[i] = 1 + rand() % 10;
        printf("%d \n", bucket[i]);
    }
    countings = entropy_calculator(bucket);
    return 0;
}

double entropy_calculator(int bucket[10]) {
    int x;
    int countcolor1 = 0, countcolor2 = 0, countcolor3 = 0,
        countcolor4 = 0, countcolor5 = 0, countcolor6 = 0;

    for (x = 0; x <= 10; ++x) {
        if (bucket[10] == 1)
            countcolor1++;

        if (bucket[10] == 2)
            countcolor2++;

        if (bucket[10] == 3)
            countcolor3++;

        if (bucket[10] == 4)
            countcolor4++;

        if (bucket[10] == 5)
            countcolor5++;

        if (bucket[10] == 6)
            countcolor6++;
    }
    printf("%d,%d,%d,%d,%d,%d",
           countcolor1, countcolor2, countcolor3,
           countcolor4, countcolor5, countcolor6);
}
```

Comment: In your own words, what does `if (bucket[10]==1)` do? Why isn't `x` used in the loop? Why is each loop condition different (`i<10` vs. `x<=10`)?  Why doesn't `entropy_calculator` return anything? Why is `i` a global variable? What warnings does your compiler give you?

Comment: sorry for writing such non-quality code, i'm really struggling as i am 1st year student

Comment: Since numbers are in range `[1..10]` why not use an `array [11]` do counting by numbers-as-index?

Comment: Consider using an array `colors[6]` instead of countcolor1 through 6.  Then your loop body simple becomes `colors[bucket[x] - 1]++;`

Comment: @AhmetCanerKaraca don't be sorry or feel bad.  We all started not knowing anything.  Sometimes we ask you questions to help you think about the problem.  We do that because we think it will help you more than just giving you the answer.

Comment: @AhmetCanerKaraca Please let me know if my answer is helpful or not!

Comment: thank you very much @oda , your answer is very helpful!

Comment: @AhmetCanerKaraca Happy I can help! Please consider accepting my answer (by clicking the check-mark next to the post) and/or upvoting it (by clicking the upward arrow next to the post) if it fixes your issue. This is completely optional and no love would be lost otherwise!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Notes on your code**

- The return type of `entropy_calculator` is `double` but you do not return anything. If you do not wish to return anything, set the return type to `void`.
- In `main`, you attempt to assign the return value of `entropy_calculator` to an `int` called `countings`. If you are going to return some `double` value, `countings` should be a `double`.
- **Undefined behavior**. According to the C Standard, behavior of a program is undefined in the event that an array subscript is out of range. `bucket` is an array of 10 integers. The valid indices of an array with `N` elements is in general `0, 1, 2, ..., N - 1`; in other words, the first element is assigned the index `0`, the second element is assigned the index `1`, ..., the `N`th element is assigned the index `N - 1`. Thus, the valid indices into the `bucket` array is any integer in the closed interval `[0, 10 - 1] = [0, 9]`. In your `entropy_calculator` function, you are attempting to access the element of `bucket` with index `10`; the only valid indices are one of `0, 1, ..., 9`.
- In `entropy_calculator`, suppose we change all the 10s to a 9 so that the loop runs from `x = 0`, `x = 1`, .. . , `x = 9` and checks of the form `([bucket[10] == j)` for some `j` in `[1, 6]` are replaced with `([bucket[9] == j)`. All of these six checks are simply checking if the 10th element of `bucket` is one of 1, 2, ..., or 6. You have disregarded the other 9 randomly-generated numbers in `bucket` so you are never involving them in the count. You are also disregarding the other possible randomly-generated values, namely, 7, 8, 9, and 10 as you are currently only comparing the 10th element of `bucket` against 1, 2, ..., and 6.

**Solution**

I assume your task is to

- generate 10 random integers in `[1, 10]` and store them in an array of `int`s, say, `bucket`.
- create a function that accepts as an argument an array of 10 `int`s (i.e. a pointer to an `int`) and prints the number of occurrences of `1`s, `2`s, ..., `10`s in the array.

To make the program slightly more general, we define the macro `MAX_LEN` and make it represent the number 10.

In `main`, first, we initialize the random number generator by setting the seed to the current time. Second, we define an array of `MAX_LEN` `int`s called `bucket`. Third, we fill each element of `bucket` with a pseudo-random integer in `[1, MAX_LEN]`. Lastly, we call the function`entropy_calculator`, passing `bucket` as the sole argument, and then `return 0`.

In the function, `entropy_calculator`, we define an array of `MAX_LEN` `int`s called `counts`, with each element initialized to zero. We create our own **internal mapping** such that the `n`th element of `counts` represents the number of `n`s found in `bucket`, for each `n` in `{1, 2, ..., MAX_LEN}`. Equivalently, for each `n` in `{1, 2, ..., MAX_LEN}`, the number of `n`s found in bucket is represented by the element of `counts` with index `n - 1`. We then loop over the elements of the `bucket` array and, using our mapping, increment the corresponding element in the `counts` array. We then print out all the elements of `counts`.

- For example, for some `i` in the set of valid indices of the arrays in our program, i.e. `{0, 1, ..., MAX_LEN - 1}`, if we find that `bucket[i]` is `5`, then we want to increment the `5`th element of `counts` (since the `n`th element of `counts` counts the number of `n`s generated) which is `counts[5 - 1]` or, more generally, `counts[bucket[i] - 1]`.

**Program**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

#define MAX_LEN 10

void entropy_calculator(int bucket[]);

int main(void) {

    /* initialize random number generator */
    srand((unsigned) time(NULL));

    /* will contain MAX_LEN random ints in [1, MAX_LEN] */
    int bucket[MAX_LEN];

    /* generate pseudo-random ints in [1, MAX_LEN], storing them in bucket */
    for (int i = 0; i < MAX_LEN; i++) {

        bucket[i] = 1 + rand() % MAX_LEN;
        printf("%d\n", bucket[i]);

    }

    entropy_calculator(bucket);

    return 0;

}

/****************************************************************************
 * entropy_calculator: given an array of MAX_LEN integers in [1, MAX_LEN],  *         *
 *                     prints the number of occurrences of each integer in  *
 *                     [1, MAX_LEN] in the supplied array                   *
 ****************************************************************************/

void entropy_calculator(int bucket[]) {

    int counts[MAX_LEN] = {0};    /* initialize counts to all 0s */
    int i;                        /* loop variable */

    for (i = 0; i < MAX_LEN; i++)
        counts[bucket[i] - 1]++;

    /* printing all elements of counts */
    for (i = 0; i < MAX_LEN; i++) {

        if (i % 4 == 0) printf("\n");
        printf(" %2d*: %d", i + 1, counts[i]);

    }
    printf("\n");

}
```

**Example Session**

```
3
9
2
6
10
9
3
8
3
1

  1*: 1  2*: 1  3*: 3  4*: 0
  5*: 0  6*: 1  7*: 0  8*: 1
  9*: 2 10*: 1
```

**Simplified version**

---

If the task is to simply generate `MAX_LEN` (macro representing the value 10) random integers in `[1, MAX_LEN]` and to count how many `1s, 2s, ..., (MAX_LEN - 1), MAX_LENs` are generated, then it can simply be done as follows.

We create an array of `MAX_LEN` integers, called `counts`. The valid indices associated with `counts` is `0, 1, ..., MAX_LEN - 1`. We form our own internal mapping such that the element of `counts` with index `n - 1` represents the number of randomly-generated `n`s for `n` in `{1, 2, ..., MAX_LEN}`.

As we generate a random integer in `[1, MAX_LEN]`, we assign it to `cur`, and we increment the element of `counts` with index `cur - 1` as this element represents the number of occurrences of the number `cur`.

**Program**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

#define MAX_LEN 10

int main(void) {

    srand((unsigned) time(NULL));    /* initialize random number generator */
    int counts[MAX_LEN] = {0};       /* initialize counts to all 0s */
    int i, cur;

    for (i = 0; i < MAX_LEN; i++) {

        cur = 1 + rand() % MAX_LEN;  /* pseudo-random int in [1, MAX_LEN] */
        printf("%d\n", cur);
        counts[cur - 1]++;

    }

    /* printing all elements of counts */
    for (i = 0; i < MAX_LEN; i++) {

        if (i % 4 == 0) printf("\n");
        printf(" %2d*: %d", i + 1, counts[i]);

    }
    printf("\n");

    return 0;

}
```

**Example Session**

```
8
4
6
2
4
1
10
9
2
10

  1*: 1  2*: 2  3*: 0  4*: 2
  5*: 0  6*: 1  7*: 0  8*: 1
  9*: 1 10*: 2
```

Answer (score -1):

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<time.h>
int i;
double entropy_calculator(int bucket[10]);
int main()
{

    srand(time(NULL));
    int countings;
    int bucket[10];
    for(i=0; i<10; ++i)
    {
        bucket[i] = 1 + rand() % 10;
        printf("%d ", bucket[i]);
    }
    printf("\n");
    countings = entropy_calculator(bucket);
    return 0;
}

double entropy_calculator(int bucket[10])
{

    int x;
    int countcolor1=0, countcolor2=0, countcolor3=0, countcolor4=0, countcolor5=0, countcolor6=0;
    for(x=0; x<10; ++x)
    {
        if (bucket[9]==1)

            countcolor1++;

        
        if (bucket[9]==2)

            countcolor2++;


        if (bucket[9]==3)

            countcolor3++;


        if (bucket[9]==4)

            countcolor4++;


        if (bucket[9]==5)

            countcolor5++;


        if (bucket[9]==6)

            countcolor6++;
             

    }
    printf("%d,%d,%d,%d,%d,%d",countcolor1,countcolor2,countcolor3,countcolor4,countcolor5,countcolor6);


}
```

Comment: You have declared the array of size 10 and the index of array is of 0 based. So, the last element is not arr[10]. It's arr[9];

Comment: Dumping code without an explanation is not helpful. Furthermore, your code is incorrect: you should compare `bucket[x]` instead of `bucket[9]`. Also remove the global variable `i` and change the return type of `entropy_calculator` to `void`.